# Illegal characters in path on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#-4.0, console-application

Hello I have the following file path:

> C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\u_ex171024.log

Which I think is perfectly valid. However, when I run the code in the production machine I always get the following exception:

```
Illegal characters in path
    in System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)
```

The poduction machine is a Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 with Framework 4.7 installed.

The app was developed with Visual Studio 2012 (Framework 4.5) and targeted x64 plataforms

The code which causes the error is this one:

```
string PathLogs = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathLogs"];
// Value of AppSettings["PathLogs"] = "C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles";

List<string> lDs = new List<string>(Directory.GetDirectories(PathLogs));

foreach (string Folder in lDs)
{
    string PathFile = Path.Combine(Folder, string.Format("u_ex{0:yyMMdd}.log", DateTime.Now));

     using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(PathFile))
     using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
     {
            string[] lData = null;
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            { ... }
     }
}
```

Today Oct/25 I ran the same code and it work without any problem. But if I try to process the file corresponding to 24th Oct. It produces the commented exception

Any help or comment will be appreciated

Comment: You need to show us the code that caused the error for us to help and to have your question help others in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the observation @ps2goat

Comment: Is this the *actual* code? This won't produce any error. EIther the string *isn't* a verbatim string, ie it *doesn't* contain `@` at the front, or there is some hidden character that looks valid but isn't. How is the path *actually* constructed ?

Comment: No repro with an actual filename as expected. All I changed was the virtual site number and the file name

Comment: Thanks for your time @PanagiotisKanavos. I changed the code to show how the path is build.

Comment: [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars(v=vs.110).aspx) tells you the characters you cannot have in the path.  Somehow, one of these characters is making it into your filename.